# Netlogo: Search in a list of turtles

Tags: list, netlogo

Let's say I have a list of turtles and each turtle in this list has a own numeric variable foo. How can I elegantly extract the turtle with the lowest value stored in foo without iterating the whole list?

Thank you in advance!

Eric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the turtle in the list with the lowest value of `foo`, then you can sort the list of turtles by the `foo` value for each turtle and then pick off the first turtle in the list.  For NetLogo v6.0 that would be (assuming `foo` is a turtle-own variable and `turtle-list` is your list of turtles):

```
first sort-by[[t1 t2] -> [foo] of t1 < [foo] of t2] turtle-list
```

Charles

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you very much for your answer. I've tried your proposal, but the list seems not to be sorted correctly.                          My code example:                                                                              breed [things thing]
things-own [inside]

to start
  clear-all
  create-things 20
  [
    set inside random 100 + 1
  ]
  let queue []
  ask things 
  [
    set queue fput self queue
  ]
  show queue
  show first sort-by [[t1 t2] -> ([inside] of t1) < ([inside] of t2)] queue
end

Comment: Forget my comment, it works! I've mixed up the who value with the content of the inside variable. Thanks again! Eric.

Answer (score 0):

it depends a bit on the context (how is the list structured, who owns it, how is it built and how frequently), but in general I'd save the list in it's own global/turtle-owned variable then use the primitive 'min-one-of' to query it. If you give a reproducible example I can help you apply this to code, but something to the effect of

```
globals [foo-list] 
;make foo-list;
let small_foo min-one-of [foo-list] 
show small_foo
```

Comment: thank you, but that's not exactly what I'am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have a 'list' of turtles, do you actually mean the data type list, or do you really have an agentset (which is the more usual NetLogo construction of a group of turtles)? If you have an agentset, look at the dictionary for the primitive `with-min`. You will want some construction like `let small_foo agentsetname with-min [foo]`

Comment: No, I really mean a list of tutles. It is a educational programm for graph search algorithms wihich uses FIFO, LIFO and a priority queue. All of them a realized by lists.